# Point a .tk Domain to a Domain Name

Tags: heroku, dns, openshift

I am hosting my website on a servce (open shift, heroku, ect) that doesn't give you a static ip. How do I point my free .tk domain to it. I set up my web site service to accept it, however, .tk domains only allow you to point to a static ip, not domain name. It has a custom dns service but am not sure how to do this. Could you please give a quick explanation. If I need a dns, please tell if there are any free service will fit the bill. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I think I may have managed to do it with a cname, now to wiat and see.

Comment: can you please explain how you did it? i.e with Heroku

Comment: Okay, read my awnser below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@siamii, I did it with a cname. After creating your .tk domain, go to the domain panel and click modify domain. On the list of options using the mydottk free domain service (The default option) add a new cname. The cname should be structered as, Host domain www.[YourDomainHere].tk and Ip Address: [your heroku web site address]. Now go to your app on heroku.com and go to domain settings on your app's settings page. Add your www.[YourDomainHere].tk to that setting and you should be good to go.

**Note:** You cannot point a top level( [YourDomainHere].tk) domain to heroku with the mydottk free domain service. The primary way you do this is to redirect from [YourDomainHere].tk to www.[YourDomainHere].tk but the free domain service cannot do that.

Comment: So I understand it is not possible to point the top level domain in any way to my app

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains It's definitely possible, just not with the free dns that mydottk gives you. If you can pass the .tk domain to another dns provider you might be able to.

Comment: Looks like now it's possible to point a top level domain to heroku with mydottk free domain service

Answer (score 2):

cname is the way to go; see our blog on how this can be done.

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way

Comment: this doesn't answer the question